# Can't see the TypeScript toolbar in WebStorm 2018.2.5

Tags: typescript, webstorm

Can't see the TypeScript toolbar in WebStorm 2018.2.5 What can I do?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 10):

The "Typescript" tool window was also missing for me, using WebStorm 2020.3. Clicking on View -> Tool Window neither showed me the Typescript tool window.
However, at the bottom right of the window, there was a text saying "Typescript X.X.X". I clicked on it and choose Compile -> Compile all. This brought the TypeScript tool window back for me!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why, but when I opened on a `.ts` file it opened the typescript toolbar, but this only worked on one project.

I opened another project and no toolbar again and clicking on the `.ts` file doesn't open the toolbar.

Comment: TypeScript tool window is not shown until you open a .ts file - this is expected behavior

Comment: then why when I open another project and open a .ts file the toolbar is not opened? I've been working with ts for many months and was always working just fine, just today is broken.

Comment: make sure that typescript service is enabled for your project

Comment: It's in the first screenshot, it's enabled

Answer (score 1):

1. File -> Invalidate Cache/Restart
2. Ensure , you  open a ts file.
3. Ensure, Preferences -> Typescript -> Enable Typescript Language Service -> Apply -> Ok

Comment: The `Typescript Language Service` checkbox is under `File -> Settings -> Language & Frameworks -> TypeScript`. _(In WebStorm version 2022.1)_

Answer (score 0):

Above answers fix part of the problem for me. Yes you do have to have the TS language service enabled in settings.
In addition to that you need to

- right click in very bottom right corner
- make sure typescript service is set to visible

[image]